# Open JupyterLab without Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there a convenient way of opening JupyterLab without opening Jupyter Notebook? I created the shortcuts for both, but I noticed that I need to open the Jupyter Notebook first then JupyterLab to avoid a blank page if otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Where do these shortcuts point?

Comment: @Anton vBR Once I opened them in Chrome, I created the shortcuts by More tools → create shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda environment then surely you can open jupyterlab without opening jupyter notebook

[image]

Comment: Yeah, my anaconda navigator also shows that. But in this case, do you have to open the anaconda navigator which allows you to open the lab? It's still not a one-click direct open?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what the problem is without seeing your shortcuts, but usually if you replace the `/tree?` in the notebook URL with `/lab` you should be able to get straight to jupyterlab.